# JavaScript Object - Call without creating it (like Math object)

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript objects. I want to create an object like the JavaScript Math object. But  it is not working (it returns nothing).

I want to create an object called Area and give it the methods square and rectangle. I want to use it the same way the Math object is used. To find the area of a square I would do:

```
var squareArea = Area.square(10); // 100
```

I chose areas for the example because it's simple.

My script is as follows:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {


    function Area() {

        function square(a) {
            area = a * a;
            return area;
        }

        function rectangle(a, b) {
            area = a * b;
            return area;    
        }

    }

    rectangleArea = Area.rectangle(10, 20);

    alert(rectangleArea);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Learn more about objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do here is make an object named `Area` with the methods you described assigned to it. The easiest and cleanest way to do this would be like so:

```
var Area = {

    square: function(a)
    {
        return a * a;
    },

    rectangle: function(a, b)
    {
        return a * b;  
    }

};
```

You can now use `Area.square()` and `Area.rectangle()` as you described.

Answer (score 7):

This will create an object called `Area` with methods on it.

```
var Area = {
    staticMethod: function() { }
};
```

Unless you want `Area` callable, don't make it a function.

Answer (score 3):

Your functions are only in scope inside the containing function, `Area`. To make them accessible through the `Area` object set the function as properties of `Area`:

```
var Area = {
    square: function(a) {
        area = a * a;
        return area;
    },
    rectangle: function(a, b) {
        area = a * b;
        return area;    
    }
}

rectangleArea = Area.rectangle(10, 20);
alert(rectangleArea);
```

It looks like you are trying to use "classes" since you made `Area` a function. You don't need to do that because you don't need multiple instances of `Area`, but if you want it do this:

```
function AreaClass(){
     // just an empty constructor
}
AreaClass.prototype.square = function(a) {
    area = a * a;
    return area;
}
AreaClass.prototype.rectangle = function(a, b) {
    area = a * b;
    return area;    
}
var Area = new AreaClass();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so there's lots of answers with code, but little explanation:

By making `Area` a function, you make the first mistake - it should be an object with functions attached.

Then, in the body of your `Area` function you are declaring more functions, but since they're inside the `Area` function they just get deleted straight away - there not actually callable form outside.

What you want is to make an object:

```
var Area = {};
```

Then attach functions to it:

```
Area.square = function(var a) {
    area = a * a;
    return area;
};
```

And so on.

That way the functions that you want to call are properties of the `Area` object.

Or you can do it inline:

```
var Area = {
    square: function(var a) {
        area = a * a;
        return area;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to simply creating a namespace for your methods (eg, `var Area = { ... }`), you can add static methods to existing classes, for example

```
function Area() { ... };

Area.square = function(a) {
    return a * a;
};
```